# step by step gflot tutorial?

Tags: java, gwt

I feel a bit dumb asking this question here, but I can't seem to find a decent [Gflot](https://github.com/nmorel/gflot) tutorial. Yes, there are tons of [examples](http://gflot2.appspot.com/#line), and you can even download the [whole code](https://github.com/nmorel/gflot/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/com/googlecode/gflot/examples) and try it out, but if you just want to create a uiBinder in a GWT project and add it to the main panel...it becomes really hard. I'm trying to add a simple LineChart to my main html file in a test GWT project.

Here is my LineExample uiBinder, directly copied from the examples:

```
public class LineExample extends DefaultActivity{

private static Binder binder = GWT.create( Binder.class );

interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, LineExample>{}

interface Style extends CssResource{
    String button();
    String darkTheme();
    String whiteTheme();
    String legendLabel();
}

/**
 * Plot
 */
@UiField( provided = true )
SimplePlot plot;

/** 
 * Button switch to dark
 */
@UiField
Button switchDark;

/**
 * Button switch to white
 */
@UiField
Button switchWhite;

/**
 * Access to UiBinder style
 */
@UiField
Style style;


public LineExample( Resources resources ){
    super( resources );
}

/**
 * Create plot
 */
public Widget createPlot(){
    PlotModel model = new PlotModel();
    PlotOptions plotOptions = PlotOptions.create();
    plotOptions.setLegendOptions( LegendOptions.create().setBackgroundOpacity( 0 )
        .setPosition( LegendPosition.NORTH_WEST ) );
    plotOptions.setGridOptions( GridOptions.create().setMargin( 5 ) );
    plotOptions.addXAxisOptions( AxisOptions.create().setFont( FontOptions.create().setColor("black").setWeight( "bold" ).setStyle( "italic" ) ) );
    plotOptions.addYAxisOptions( AxisOptions.create().setFont( FontOptions.create().setColor( "black" ).setWeight( "bold" ).setStyle( "italic" ) ) );

    // create the plot
    plot = new SimplePlot( model, plotOptions );

    // add data
    generateRandomData();

    return binder.createAndBindUi( this );
}

/**
 * On click on the generate button, we clear the current data and generate new ones
 *
 * @param e click event
 */
@UiHandler( "generate" )
void onClickGenerate( ClickEvent e ){
    plot.getModel().removeAllSeries();
    generateRandomData();
    plot.redraw();
}

/**
 * Generate random data
 */
private void generateRandomData(){
    int nbSeries = Random.nextInt( 5 ) + 1;
    for ( int i = 0; i < nbSeries; i++ ){
        plot.getModel().addSeries( Series.of( "Random Series " + i ) );
    }
    for ( int i = 1; i < 13; i++ ){
        for ( SeriesHandler series : plot.getModel().getHandlers() ){
            series.add( DataPoint.of( i, Random.nextInt( 30 ) ) );
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Switch to dark theme
 *
 * @param e click event
 */
@UiHandler( "switchDark" )
void onClickSwitchToDark( ClickEvent e ){
    switchDark.setVisible( false );
    switchWhite.setVisible( true );

    plot.removeStyleName( style.whiteTheme() );
    plot.addStyleName( style.darkTheme() );
    plot.getOptions().getXAxisOptions().getFont().setColor( "white" );
    plot.getOptions().getXAxisOptions().setTickColor( "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)" );
    plot.getOptions().getYAxisOptions().getFont().setColor( "white" );
    plot.getOptions().getYAxisOptions().setTickColor( "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)" );
    plot.getOptions().getGridOptions().setBorderColor( "white" );
    plot.redraw();
}

/**
 * Switch to white theme
 *
 * @param e click event
 */
@UiHandler( "switchWhite" )
void onClickSwitchToWhite( ClickEvent e ){
    switchDark.setVisible( true );
    switchWhite.setVisible( false );

    plot.removeStyleName( style.darkTheme() );
    plot.addStyleName( style.whiteTheme() );
    plot.getOptions().getXAxisOptions().getFont().setColor( "black" );
    plot.getOptions().getXAxisOptions().clearTickColor();
    plot.getOptions().getYAxisOptions().getFont().setColor( "black" );
    plot.getOptions().getYAxisOptions().clearTickColor();
    plot.getOptions().getGridOptions().clearBorderColor();
    plot.redraw();
}
```

}

Here is the correspoding LineExample.ui.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"      xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
xmlns:p="urn:import:com.googlecode.gflot.client">

<ui:style type='gflot.sample.client.LineExample.Style'>
 .button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.darkTheme {
  background-color: black;
}

@external legendLabel;
.darkTheme .legendLabel {
    color: white;
}

.whiteTheme .legendLabel {
  color: black;
}
```

Generate
    Switch to dark
    Switch to white

The Resources file used:

```
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {
@Source( "gflot.css" )
Style style();

public interface Style extends CssResource{
    String headerContainer();
    String headerTitle();
    String headerDescription();
    String headerHomePageLink();
    String menuScrollContainer();
    String menuContainer();
    String menuCategory();
    String menuLink();
    String menuLinkSelected();
    String sourceContainer();
    String sourceLink();
    String sourceLinkSelected();
    String mainScrollContainer();
    String mainContainer();
}
```

}

And the css file, gflot.css:

```
@def headerBgColor #0D0D0D;
@def mainBgColor #FFF7FF;
body {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: mainBgColor;
    color: #0D0D0D;
}

@external gwt-Button;
.gwt-Button {
/*         background-color: #D14836; */
/*         background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #DD4B39, #D14836); */
/*         background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #DD4B39, #D14836); */
/*         background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #DD4B39, #D14836); */
/*         background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #DD4B39, #D14836); */
/*         background-image: linear-gradient(top, #DD4B39, #D14836); */
/*         border: 1px solid transparent; */
/*         height: 27px; */
/*         line-height: 27px; */
/*         padding: 0px 8px; */
/*         outline: 0; */
/*         font-weight: bold; */
/*         -webkit-border-radius: 5px; */
/*         -moz-border-radius: 5px; */
/*         border-radius: 5px; */
/*         cursor: pointer; */
}

.headerContainer {
    margin: 8px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: headerBgColor;
    color: white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
}

.headerContainer a {
    color: white;
}

.headerTitle {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

 .headerDescription {
    font-style: italic;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.headerHomePageLink {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.menuScrollContainer {

}

.menuContainer {

}

.menuCategory {
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.menuLink {
    margin: 0px 10px;
}

.menuLink a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    color: black;
    outline: 0px;
}

.menuLinkSelected a {
    background-color: #8C2E0B;
    color: white;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}

.menuLink a:hover {
    background-color: #8C501C;
    color: white;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}

.sourceContainer {
    padding: 10px;
}

.sourceLink {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 3px;
    color: black;
}

.sourceLink:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.sourceLinkSelected {
    color: grey;
 }

.sourceLinkSelected:hover {
    cursor: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.mainScrollContainer {
    margin: 5px;
}

.mainContainer {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Now, what I don't know how to proceed is adding the widget to my main panel...here is my EntryPoint class, where I'm adding an already existing widget I created before:

```
public class Gflot_example implements EntryPoint {
public void onModuleLoad() {
  RootPanel.get().add(new Login());
  //RootPanel.get().add(???);   >> new LineExample() does not look like the way to proceed here 
}
```

I've checked the [EntryPoint](https://github.com/nmorel/gflot/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/googlecode/gflot/examples/client/GFlotExamples.java) in the examples, but it calls a MainWidow class that does lots of stuff I really don't know what is going on there...anyone has a working example NOT from the official examples?

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important part of the examples is the `createPlot()` method in each one. Rest of the stuff is used to handle history and source code viewing.

To add a `SimplePlot` to your `RootPanel`, just do the following :

- Create a `PlotModel` and add your data to it
- Create a `PlotOptions` and define the options you want
- Create a `SimplePlot` with the model and options you created
- Add the `SimplePlot` to your `RootPanel`

Basically, just copy the `createPlot()` method, put it inside your EntryPoint and do `RootPanel.get().add(createPlot());`

If you haven't done it yet, you also need to include the gflot module. Add `<inherits name='com.googlecode.gflot.GFlot'/>` to your module descriptor XML file.

Comment: Hello Nicolas, you're the main developer of Gflot right? Let me say thanks for your work first, is great to have Flots in GWT! I'll try what you suggest and let you know what happens! Regards, Alex

Comment: That's right :) Don't hesitate to ask questions, I never took the time to write a proper documentation!

Comment: Sorry I could not answer before...this works!! I always tought that the charts have to be used within a uiBinder, but I now see this is not necessary...I'll write a simple tutorial in my blog about how to do some examples..thanks again Nicolas!